# Bubble Sorting Linked List

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

I have worked out a sorting function with a helper swapper(). The function sorts nodes in the list by their address in memory in descending order (highest address to lowest address).

The function sorts fine as long as the head of the list does not change, but when the head changes, all that returns is the head and whatever was after it. Somewhere I am losing the rest of the list and I can't figure it out.

My function so far:

```
void swapper(NODE *left, NODE *right)
{
    if(left->prev)
        left->prev->next = right;
    if(right->next)
        right->next->prev = left;

    left->next = right->next;
    right->prev = left->prev;

    right->next = left;
    left->prev = right;
}
NODE *sort_nodes(NODE *head)
{
    NODE *new_second, *new_first, *list = head;
    int swaps;
    do{
        swaps = 0;
        while(list)
        {
            if(&(*list) < &(*(list->next)))
            {
                swapper(list, list->next);
                swaps = 1;
            }
            list = list->next;
        }
        list = head;
    }while(swaps);
    return list;
}
```

Example output if the head of the list is the third node declared in the list:

```
Unsorted: 0x93657050 -> 0x936570d0 -> 0x93657070 -> 0x93657090 -> 0x93657030 -> 0x936570b0 -> 0x93657010 -> NULL
Sorted:   0x93657050 -> 0x93657030 -> 0x93657010 -> NULL
```

Comment: `if (&(*list) < ..` is strange. Why not just `if (list < ...)` ?

Comment: I'm more interested in the reason you sort by *pointer* and not by "value" stored in the nodes? It really makes no sense, as the pointers to the nodes really have no relation to each other, they are just abitrary addresses. What is the requirement for that?

Comment: I understand that their addresses really have no value, but I want to sort them by that attribute in memory regardless. So, in order to acquire the address of the struct _Node (NODE) I take the address of the dereferenced pointer.

Comment: As for another possible way of solving your problem: Recreate the list instead. "Pop" (remove) the first node from the list, make it the head of a new list. Then "pop" the next node, and insert it at the correct position in the new list. Iterate until there are no more nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple when you think about it.

You have

```
head -> A -> B
```

Then you swap A and B without changing head, so you get

```
head -|
      v
 B -> A
```

If you swap the head element, you need to move the head pointer to the new head.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* structure for a node */
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

/* Function to insert a node at the begining of a linked lsit */
void insertAtTheBegin(struct Node **start_ref, int data);

/* Function to bubble sort the given linked lsit */
void bubbleSort(struct Node *start);

/* Function to swap data of two nodes a and b*/
void swap(struct Node *a, struct Node *b);

/* Function to print nodes in a given linked list */
void printList(struct Node *start);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 56, 2, 11, 1, 90};
    int list_size, i;

    /* start with empty linked list */
    struct Node *start = NULL;

    /* Create linked list from the array arr[].
      Created linked list will be 1->11->2->56->12 */
    for (i = 0; i< 6; i++)
        insertAtTheBegin(&start, arr[i]);

    /* print list before sorting */
    printf("\n Linked list before sorting ");
    printList(start);

    /* sort the linked list */
    bubbleSort(start);

    /* print list after sorting */
    printf("\n Linked list after sorting ");
    printList(start);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}


/* Function to insert a node at the begining of a linked lsit */
void insertAtTheBegin(struct Node **start_ref, int data)
{
    struct Node *ptr1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr1->data = data;
    ptr1->next = *start_ref;
    *start_ref = ptr1;
}

/* Function to print nodes in a given linked list */
void printList(struct Node *start)
{
    struct Node *temp = start;
    printf("\n");
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

/* Bubble sort the given linked lsit */
void bubbleSort(struct Node *start)
{
    int swapped, i;
    struct Node *ptr1;
    struct Node *lptr = NULL;

    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (ptr1 == NULL)
        return;

    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = start;

        while (ptr1->next != lptr)
        {
            if (ptr1->data > ptr1->next->data)
            { 
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
}

/* function to swap data of two nodes a and b*/
void swap(struct Node *a, struct Node *b)
{
    int temp = a->data;
    a->data = b->data;
    b->data = temp;
}
```